# How do I launch a program from command line without opening a new cmd window?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to programmatically execute an external file from `cmd` using this command:

```
START "filepath"
```

Where `"filepath"` is the path of my file. It opens fine but it also open a new command prompt window.

So, which is the right command for opening an external program without opening a new window?

Comment: What sort of external file what are you trying to programatically execute it from?

Comment: I want to execute an *.exe file using CMD ...   the comand pasted by me below, opens that file, but also opens a new cmd window ...  din you have the right script for this?

Comment: John Watts gave you the answer

Answer (score 29):

In Windows 7+ the first quotations will be the title to the `cmd` window to open the program:

```
start "title" "C:\path\program.exe"
```

Formatting your command like the above will temporarily open a `cmd` window that goes away as fast as it comes up so you really never see it. It also allows you to open more than one program without waiting for the first one to close first.

Comment: Saved my life, needed to use `start "" "C:\path\program.exe"`

Comment: @cprcrack Wow! I'm glad your life was spared. Be careful who you let into your life!

Answer (score 11):

Add /B, as documented in the command-line help for start:

```
C:\>start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
  [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
  [/NODE <NUMA node>] [/AFFINITY <hex affinity mask>] [/WAIT] [/B]
  [command/program] [parameters]

"title"     Title to display in window title bar.
path        Starting directory.
B           Start application without creating a new window. The
            application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
            enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
            the application.
```

Comment: Programs started this way still receive `^Break` when the parent console is closed. Instead I start without `/B` and then hide the new console window with `cmdow "<title>" /HID`

Answer (score 6):

I think if you closed a program

```
taskkill /f /im "winamp.exe" 
//....(winamp.exe is example)...
```

end, so 
if you want to start a program that you can use

```
start "" /normal winamp.exe
```

(/norma,/max/min are that process value cpu)

ALSO

start "filepath"[image]

if you want command line without openning an new window
you write that

start /b "filepath"[image]

/B is Start application without creating a new window. The
                application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
                enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
                the application.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the double quote, this works in Windows 7:

```
start C:\ProgramFiles\folderName\app.exe
```

If you want to maximize the window, try this:

```
start /MAX C:\ProgramFiles\folderName\app.exe
```

Your command `START "filepath"` will start a command prompt and change the command prompt title to `filepath`.

Try to run `start /?` in windows command prompt and you will get more info.

Comment: what if i have space in the path.

Comment: add quotation mark to those folder name with space. For example: `start C:\"Program Files"\"my application"\app.exe`

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it via CMD as you say, then you can just enter the command like so:

```
path\to\your.exe
```

which will open it within the same window. For example in C++:

```
system("path\\to\\your.exe"); // Double backslash for escaping
```

will open `your.exe` in the current CMD window. Likewise to start with a new window, just go for:

```
system("start path\\to\\your.exe");
```

If you go for the first option, you would have to clear your screen unless you wanted to have the command to open `your.exe` on the screen still.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `call` command...

Type: `call /?`

Usage: `call [drive:][path]filename [batch-parameters]`

For example `call "Example File/Input File/My Program.bat"` [This is also capable with calling files that have a *.exe*, *.cmd*, *.txt*, etc.

***NOTE: THIS COMMAND DOES NOT ALWAYS WORK!!!***

Not all computers are capable to run this command, but if it does work than it is very useful, and you won't have to open a brand new window...

Answer (score 0):

I got it working from [qkzhu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20533779) but instead of using MAX change it to MIN and window will close super fast.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
:: Title not needed:
start /MIN  mysqld.exe
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

20190907

OS: Win 10

I'm making an exe in c++, for some reason usting **START** make my program fail.

So, just use quotes:

"c:\folder\program.exe"

Answer (score 0):

It's easier and safer to use the explorer.exe to start files/executeables, it is also opening files with the associated program and runs executables directly, if you execute:

```
start "" "%windir%\explorer.exe" "C:\Path\To\some.pdf"
```

If `*.PDF` files are not associated with any program. This works similar to a double-click and triggers the "open with program" dialog.

```
start "" "%windir%\explorer.exe" "%windir%\system32\calc.exe"
```

Will bring up the calculator.

```
start "" "%windir%\explorer.exe" "C:\pagefile.sys"
```

Will bring up a warning like: *You are trying to open a system file (*.sys)... choose a programm...*

### Important

explorer.exe always requires the full path to the executable/file, not the relative path.
If you want to use relative paths, use

```
start "" "%windir%\explorer.exe" "relative\file.pdf","C:\dir\"
```

#### Security related

Using `start "" "some\file.dat"` will **try to execute the file as binary file** and start it, if possible. This can end in security related issues.
You can test it by creating a copy of `cmd.exe` calling it `dummy.dat` and start it using `start dummy.dat`

Answer (score -1):

1-Open you folder that contains your application in the File Explorer.
2-Press SHIFT and Right Click in White Space.
3-Click on "Open command window here".
4-Run your application. (you can type some of the first characters of application name and press Up Arrow Key OR Down Arrow Key)