# Hide Command Line when running a Ruby Program

Tags: ruby, git, bash

I recently finished my game for my AP Computer Science AB Final (if you know GIT and Git Bash and have ruby installed, you can clone the game here: https://github.com/gerberhe/Final_Game).

I made a shortcut called "Final Game", that when I double-click on it, it runs my game. This works fine with the code I used to do this, and it opens my game in a Gosu window.

However, double-clicking/running this shortcut file ALSO opens a blank command prompt/cmd window that does nothing, shows nothing, and just closes as soon as I close the game.

Question is, is there any code or any way I can make it so that when I run this shortcut file, the game appears, but the cmd line that also opens is hidden, or simply just doesn't open?

This isn't necessary, but would make the game seem a bit more professional and aesthetically pleasing. Thanks!

Also, if you decide to try the game, note that there are some bugs with it currently that I am planning on fixing, but that aren't necessary to the fluidity and work ability of the game.

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm guessing this is a Windows problem rather than a Ruby or programming problem.  The OP does not divulge the platform but this is typical of Windows, and a common FAQ.

Comment: This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010103/launch-a-program-from-command-line-without-opening-a-new-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having trouble dissecting the .lnk file, but I believe you can simulate what you want in the command line by running

```
ruby main.rb &
```

instead of `ruby main.rb`. Once you have that, I think you can create a .bat file with the above line and it *should* run correctly.

**Explanation:**
The common reason the command prompt runs is because the command prompt is actually running the game inside itself and waiting for you to finish before completing the "run the game" script. The & says "run the game outside of this command prompt (inside a new thread)". Then after creating the new thread, it sees that it has finished execution of the script and closes itself, leaving your game to run on it's own.

Comment: So, how would I do this within the code? Basically, when someone double-clicks on the shortcut, it runs main.rb is all it does, making the game run.

Comment: Instead of making a shortcut, make a bat script with `ruby main.rb &` as the only line in it. If you want, you can make a shortcut to that bat script.

If you are very new to bat script, just make a text file, put the above line in the file, then rename the file to something like `run.bat`.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention @Harrison. See my comment above. If it helps I can edit it into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try forking in/around your main function.
That way it process will finish and release the shell but the new forked process will continue until terminated from the GUI.