# Running a program after copy file, in one Windows CMD line?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, command-line, cmd, post-build-event

I try to create visual studio post-build event command line and i want:

1. to kill process if exist;
2. copy file;
3. launch a program;

> start taskkill /f /im app.exe /t & xcopy /y
>   "$(TargetPath)" "C:\Program Files (x86)\path\$(TargetFilename)" & start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\program\app.exe"

I use `start taskkill /f /im app.exe /t`instead of `taskkill /f /im app.exe /t` because if the process not exists i get `not found` error

Now all tree command runs OK with no error but the last command not launch the program but if i execute this command separately the program is executed.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you need to pass that first empty string argument to the third `start`?

Comment: here i see the first argument is the title http://stackoverflow.com/a/17298306/2327332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Timing Problem.

Try:

```
start /wait taskkill /f /im app.exe /t & xcopy /y "D:\Workspaces\Dev\path\bin\Debug\my.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\path\my.dll" & start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\program\app.exe"
```

Comment: yes. this was the problem. this ```wait ``` solve my problem.thanks Stephan.