# how to open a program using command prompt?

Tags: command-line

I followed the following

[tutorial open program from cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010103/launch-a-program-from-command-line-without-opening-a-new-window)

The command I used is: Start "dBox" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dropbox\Client\Dropbox.exe"

I would expect to have a new cmd windows with title dBox which is gonna open my program... It does nothing, no message..

They suggest the same things on other website. Some suggest removing the " for the second parameter, however I have spaces in the path so it is not suggested...

I cannot see what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically want a new cmd window with that specific title, from which your program is run, you may try the following:

> <s>start "dBox" cmd | "c:\program files (x86)\dropbox\client\dropbox.exe"</s>
>
> start "dBox" cmd | (start /d "c:\program files (x86)\dropbox\client" dropbox.exe)

I don't have DropBox installed, but this works for other executables, so it should work for you.

Walking through the code, what you want first of all is a new command window, and running the DropBox executable is subsequent to that, so let's at least see how to get a new cmd window with your title going: `start "dBox" cmd`

Now, how do we repeat that while also getting another executable to run from that window?  This is where the "|" (pipe) symbol comes into play, which is for redirection.  The documentation says that the output from the command on the left is piped into the command on the right.  We want a new process started from a new cmd window, and the only way I've been able to get that to work (seemingly so, anyway) is by using `start` twice.

You can read more about redirection [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

**Edit:**
The first command is crossed out because I realized it made the process a child of the original cmd window.  The giveaway is that the original cmd window is unusable until the child process is killed.  I can't confirm, at the moment, if the second command does the trick exactly as stated in the question.

Comment: thx a lot for you answer! I realise that the the parameter /home is normally passed as parameters to the program. Can I open it this way?

Comment: Please note the correction.
As for parameters passed to dropbox.exe, start allows for their inclusion at the end of the command.  I would try `...ox\client" dropbox.exe /home)`

Comment: Your answer is **utterly wrong**. Please double check both [syntax-redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) and [start command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) articles.

Answer (score 2):

> I would expect to have a new cmd windows with title dBox which is
>   gonna open my program...

Next [`start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) should do the task:

```
Start "dBox" cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dropbox\Client\Dropbox.exe"
```

I do not have `Dropbox.exe` installed. Therefore I could suppose that it's either `console` or `GUI` application or a `service`. Let's substitute `Dropbox.exe` with typical executables of that type:

**Console application** (`tasklist.exe`): 
[`tasklist.exe` displays all running applications and services with their Process ID (`PID`)](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) in new `cmd` windows of title `dBox`:

```
start "dBox" cmd /K "C:\Windows\System32\tasklist.exe"
```

**GUI application** (`iexplore.exe`): 
new `cmd` windows has title `dBox - "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"` and *Internet Explorer* starts.

```
start "dBox" cmd /K "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

**Service**: not tested yet; it would exceed original  question topic.