# python is launching in another window

Tags: python, windows-server-2012-r2

I have python installed on Win server 2012, it works find when launched from cmd, however when the server reboot, python won't open in the same window command, instead it opens another window .

The only fix I find is to reinstall python, but after another reboot the same issue occurs, how to fix this permanently

[image: python opening in another window]

Comment: try this: "/b python"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I launch a program from command line without opening a new cmd window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010103/how-do-i-launch-a-program-from-command-line-without-opening-a-new-cmd-window)

Comment: I relaunched the installer with 'repair' option and the problem was solved, but I'm sure if I restart the system the problem will appear again. Thank guys